# How to create a UITableView with editable components?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I was wondering how to create a UITableView with editable components.

If you look at the network settings in the iphone, where you can enter the static ip address, etc.

How to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

http://furbo.org/2009/04/30/matt-gallagher-deserves-a-medal/

Check out that blog post. There's a link to some code named Generic Tables that will give you exactly what you need.

You may have to update some of the code to be 3.0 compatible, but that's just a case of updating the table cell init methods to use style instead of frame.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but it lead the way

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it wasn't quite what you were looking for? What does it lack?  It has table cells with editable fields like the IP address field in the network settings. It has button cells, cells with switch controls, etc.

Answer (score 2):

TaggedLocations project is a very good example of a UITableView with editable components.

You can see this example in Sample code library of Apple iOS:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TaggedLocations/Introduction/Intro.html

Regards